# Can you use the abbreviation 'ID' as a verb?

Tags: verbs, abbreviations

Although I could substitute '*identify*' in place of 'ID', would it be considered improper to use 'ID' as a verb? Here's what I mean:

> That boy looks underage, I think we should ?ID him.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think I've read a similar sentence in some thriller with cops at work.

Comment: I might call it _informal_, but I don't think I'd go so far as to call it _improper_.

Comment: *Can you use the abbreviation 'ID' as a verb?*  Yes, I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/id) as a synonym of *identify*, and certainly most people would know what you meant if you said it. It comes across as a little informal and reminiscent of police jargon. If you're talking about IDing someone specifically to verify his age (as in your example), you may also hear the colloquialism *to card*.

Comment: Yes you can. It's done quite frequently. Watch the evening news and you're likely to hear "Police have IDed (sp?) the killer..." or "Police are asking for your help to ID the suspect in this video."

Comment: I agree, it is common, especially in spoken English.  But what is the spelling you want?  Maybe *ID'd*  ... Then there would be *She IDs people at the door*  But probably not *ID's* ...  Of course if it is a verb we also need *IDing* and *IDer* and so on.

Answer (score 0):

FRINGE Season 1 Episode 19 by the protagonist:
"We canvas the area to ID her."

Comment: Please clarify what you are referring to by "FRINGE Season 1 Episode 19". This site is read world-wide and we do not all immediately recognise films, TV shows, etc. from another country.